# AWS Lambda Java "Failed to connect to service endpoint:" despite supplying the endpoint with .withEndpointConfiguration

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Please help me diagnose the error message "Failed to connect to service endpoint:". That is the complete error message. Kind of looks like it can't find the endpoint, but as you can see below, I do supply the endpoint with the ".withEndpointConfiguration" method.

Here is my code:

```
package xyz.bombchu;

import java.util.HashMap;
import com.amazonaws.ClientConfiguration;
import com.amazonaws.auth.InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.regions.Regions;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDB;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.DynamoDB;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.AttributeValue;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestHandler;

public class LambdaFunctionHandler implements RequestHandler<Object, String> {

    DynamoDB ddb;

    @Override
    public String handleRequest(Object input, Context context) {

        Regions REGION = Regions.AP_SOUTHEAST_2;

        HashMap<String, AttributeValue> item_values =
                new HashMap<String, AttributeValue>();

        String relativeTime = "02000001";
        item_values.put("dateTime", new AttributeValue().withN(relativeTime));
        item_values.put("cID", new AttributeValue("TEST"));

        AmazonDynamoDB ddb = AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard()
                .withEndpointConfiguration(new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration("dynamodb.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com", "ap-southeast-2"))
                .withCredentials(new InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider())
                .withClientConfiguration(new ClientConfiguration())
                .build();

        try {
            ddb.putItem("myTableTest", item_values);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: From the command line of the machine where this code is running, try this command: `curl https://dynamodb.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com`  If you get any reaponse at all other than *"healthy: dynamodb.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com"* then the problem is a problem with your network, not your code.

Comment: It runs fine on EC2. I'll adapt what you say and include a bit of okhttp code to send a GET to the endpoint similar to curl. Thank you for the suggestion. I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: Hi Michael, I've finished testing whether the Lambda can reach dynamodb.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com using http with the okhttp3 libraries and it can successfully do this so I think I can conclude that it is not a general network connectivity problem because okhttp3 can connect and then when it gets down to the dynamoDB method it fails with "Failed to connect to service endpoint:". I'll upload the code of what I've done tomorrow.

Comment: Example of another region: `curl -s https://dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com`